# PHP in Wordpress, need to change label&button text

Tags: php, wordpress

```
//Add filter to change ask question link text
    $label = apply_filters( 'dwqa_ask_question_link_label', $label );
```

There is a `button` and on top of this is `text`. How can I change this `text`. In the code, is there comment to add filter? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses filter to allow customization of the core, plugins etc pp.

What will happen is that WP will look for filters for dwqa_ask_question_link_label (multiple filters are allowed), give them $label and return the value that it gets back from the filters.

You can add filters with `add_filter`. Your function will then get the original value for $label an can return whatever you want to see used as $label.

A simple example:

```
add_filter("dwqa_ask_question_link_label", function($label) {
    return strrev($label);
});
```

You can use a function name instead of a function as the second parameter.
Optionally, you can add two integer parameters:

- priority (which orders the different filters that can be applied to the data, lower numbers run first, default 10) and
- the number of arguments your function expects. Since a filter can give your function multiple arguments to work with, it's up to you to say how many you want. The default is 1. It doesn't hurt if you say you "expect" more than there actually are, but when you ask for 1, you will only get one, even if there are more available.